# I have Twitter token and secret. I want to get Twitter screen name. how do I do it in Twitterizer?

Tags: twitterizer

Hi since there was no response I changed my question.

I have the token and secret from Twitterizer. but i dont have the username. How can I get the username by using these tokens?

the TwitterUser.Show() method requires username or id, i dont have both!

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no method available in previous releases, however, in the 2.3 preview (that I published about an hour ago) there is a new method you can use for this:

```
TwitterAccount.VerifyCredentials(OAuthTokens)
```

You should really store the user name or (even better) the user ID along with the access token, since many methods require at one or the other.

Comment: Hi R Smith, thanks so much, yes, I will be storing username and id from now on.. I have about 6 groups with no info I will have to send them a mail ask them for the details or something. thank you very much for the update. Also, If you are "DigitallyBorn" from the main Twitterizer site, I tried to reply to your site but was unable because I couldnt see any image in the captcha (for this post: http://forums.twitterizer.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=106 ) Thank you very much again!

Comment: I am downloading it now, will update here on how it goes. Thanks :)

Comment: I am that very person. Let me know if the captcha continues to malfunction and I'll spend some time looking for a new solution.